# AngularJS + UI-Grid + Bootstrap tab + Application Performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I am using bootstrap (uib) tabs, angular 1, angular-ui-grid. Each tab contains a single grid and each tab can also have sub tabs.
I am facing sever performance issue in application.

Data nature - Tree structured which can not be paginated. And size could be in MB's.
I tried 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:**
I used ng-show to render grid in each tab, which keeps DOM in browser while tab switching. 
It really slows down the application when there are multiple tabs open.

**Approach 2:**
If I use ng-if to render grid in each tab, which removes DOM while tab switching, takes much time in tab switching. 
Because it has to rerender whole grid again. And after that I need to apply state changes again on that grid to restore 
previous state.

Comment: Can you load grids on demand and not all at once? Something like: `<uib-tab index="$index" select="load_grid($index)">{{tab.content}}</uib-tab>`

Comment: Yes, I am doing that in second approach. In that case it takes much time to render.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can continue to do with approach 2, but follow these steps:

1. Init all grids without data
2. Just load data for first grid, bind data to it.
3. Load data for others grids. Keep them in some variables.
4. When user click on other tabs, bind related data.

If you want real-time data when click on other tags, forget step no.3, when user click on other grids, make an ajax call to get data and bind them to grid.